# How can I avoid connecting gaps in pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df_subset = norm_inspect_data_df.iloc[anomalous_data_indices]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(norm_inspect_data_df)
df_subset
ax.plot(new_df, color='r', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

where anomalous_data_indices = `array([ 2421,  2421,  2422, ..., 45614, 45614, 45615])`

norm_inspect_data_df.shape = `(52782, 1)`

df_subset.shape = `(5508, 1)`

Again, how to avoid these connecting lines between dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `linewidth=0` parameter to the second `ax.plot`:

```
ax.plot(new_df, color='r', marker='o', linewidth=0)
```

Alternatively, use [matplotlib scatter plot](http://matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), e.g.

```
ax.scatter(x=anomalous_data_indices, y=norm_inspect_data_df[anomalous_data_indices])
```

If you can supply your data structure, I can give a more precise answer.

The result will look like
[image]

Comment: `ax.plot(new_df, color='r', marker='o', linewidth=0)` works for me! Vote correct